# "In place" update in Android SQLite database not working with rawQuery

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to execute an "in place" update SQL Query on an SQLite database in my android application. The query is of the form:

> update table T set column = column + 1 where someOtherColumn = aValue

I tried executing this query with `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(updateQuery, "someOtherColumn = ?", new String{}[aValue])` but I find that the column is not incremented.  When I run the same query with the usual `SQLiteDatabase.update(...)` it works fine, but this requires me to fetch the old column value, update it outside and then execute `update()` which is probably less efficient since it requires a select and then an update.

Is there some way I can update "in place" by using the first query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way I can update "in place" by using the first query?

That's not a query. It's an `UPDATE` statement. It does not return a result set. Use it with `execSQL()`, not `rawQuery()`.

> but this requires me to fetch the old column value, update it outside and then execute update() which is probably less efficient since it requires a select and then an update

This is the way all SQL databases work. Now, those that offer stored procedures may be able to let you do an `UPDATE` and a `SELECT` in one request, but it is *still* an `UPDATE` and a `SELECT`. Furthermore, SQLite does not support stored procedures, at least when I last looked.