# "SQLException: not an error" when updating a SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

when trying to update my database through queries that I get from an internet page, I get an exception.. Here is the code:

```
url = new URL(Database.Munawwat_UpdateDB_URL);

                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    File dbfile = new File(Database.Munawwat_Database_PATH);
                    if (!dbfile.exists()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Munawwat_List.this, "error in db location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
                    String query = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        if (!line.contains("WHERE"))
                            query += line + "\n";
                        else {
                            query += line.trim();
                            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                            c.moveToFirst();

                            c.close();

                            query = "";
                        }

                    db.close();
                    reader.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Logcat:

```
 14:52:46.136: E/SQLiteQuery(17802): exception: not an error; query: UPDATE Adab SET Body="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCBCBCB" WHERE _id=4 10-14
 14:52:47.484: W/System.err(17802): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error 10-14
 14:52:47.496: W/System.err(17802): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.nativeFillWindow(Native Method) 10-14 
 14:52:47.503: W/System.err(17802): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:86) 10-14 
 14:52:47.511: W/System.err(17802): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164) 10-14 
 14:52:47.523: W/System.err(17802): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156) 10-14 
 14:52:47.527: W/System.err(17802): at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:161) 10-14 
 14:52:47.527: W/System.err(17802): at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:201) 10-14 
 14:52:47.531: W/System.err(17802): at omar.Munawwat_List$2.onClick(Munawwat_List.java:141) 10-14
 14:52:47.531: W/System.err(17802): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 10-14
 14:52:47.535: W/System.err(17802): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 10-14
 14:52:47.535: W/System.err(17802): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 10-14
 14:52:47.535: W/System.err(17802): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 10-14
 14:52:47.539: W/System.err(17802): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-14    
 14:52:47.539: W/System.err(17802): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575) 10-14
 14:52:47.539: W/System.err(17802): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-14
 14:52:47.539: W/System.err(17802): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-14 
 14:52:47.542: W/System.err(17802): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 10-14 
 14:52:47.542: W/System.err(17802): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-14
 14:52:47.546: W/System.err(17802): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So the database doesnt get updated.. Why is this?

Comment: can you post what the line string is when this code fails?

Comment: @MikeIsrael     "UPDATE Adab SET Body="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCBCBCB" WHERE _id=4".. The exception is thrown when executing the "c.moveToFirst();" line..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query contains a string constant enclosed in double quotes `"`.  It needs to be enclosed in single quotes `'`.

Edit: Barak's answer points out the main problem.  You should use execSQL instead of rawQuery, because you are not expecting a cursor back.

Comment: I changed them but I still get the same exception =\

Comment: Actual problem is described in Barak's answer below.  You are expecting a Cursor back from an update statement, and you won't get it.  Use execSQL instead of rawQuery.

Comment: tried execSQL.. same error :( I'm trying with the myDB.update() method

Comment: don't think this is the issue but what happens if you escape regular quotes like "UPD....\"AAA...\"..."?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `rawQuery` to do an update, you should not do that (or you will get exceptions).  `rawQuery` expects the DB to return a cursor to it, and an update does not do that, so you get an exception.

You should to use the `update` convenience method or the `execSQL` method to do updates as they don't require a cursor to be returned.

Comment: Where have you seen that you can not run an update in rawQuery?  I have never heard of that limitation before and I think I have even successfully run a rawQuery using update before.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it to "you shouldn't or you will get an exception".  Pretty much means cannot in my book, but if you like having exceptions coming from your code....  and since there are answers on this site from people who have written *books* about Android ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8275275/1105376)) saying not to do it, I think it might be a good idea to not do it.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't see anywhere in that link evidence that calling an update with rawQuery throws an exception.  I am not saying it is wise, but does not seem to be the issue with this question.